# How to delete all files in a folder inside an archive with 7zip?

Tags: batch-file, archive, 7zip

I have an archive file, which has a lot of folders inside of it:

```
- myfile.zip
  - folder1
  - folder2
  - folder3
     - folder3file1.txt
     - folder3file2.txt
```

How can I delete all files from the folder3, without deleting that folder, in one command line?

I know only the way to delete the folder3, and then add it as a new, empty folder, but this causes double 7zip information printing to command line.

Or how could I set to not to print the 7zip informations during 7z commands?

Comment: Have you tried `7z d myfile.zip folder3\*`?

Comment: Yes I tried, forget to write it: it also deletes the folder3.. makes no sense...

Comment: I have tested it now with the command line version (`7za.exe`) and listing the contents with `7za l myfile.zip` shows the folder.

Comment: Also, after files deletion, extracting the file (`7za x myfile.zip`) recreates the folder.

Comment: I am using 7-Zip 16.02, and there is no folder3 folder after the deletion command: `7z d myfile.zip folder3\*`

Comment: `7-Zip (a) [32] 16.04`

Comment: Tested with `7-Zip [32] 16.04` (`7z.exe`) and also works

Comment: Tested with `7-Zip (a) [32] 16.02` (`7za.exe`) and also works. Sorry, at this moment I can not install a 16.02 version of `7z.exe` to test

Comment: then I just don't know. but thanks for helping me